# How to change value after delay by using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created basic application based on `angularjs`

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    My name is 
    <input type="text"/>   
    Val: {{val}}
    <br/>
    <button ng-disabled="val">Submit</button>        
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

var glob;
function Ctrl($scope) {      
    glob = $scope;    
     $scope.val = false;

     window.setTimeout(function() {
            $scope.val = true;
        }, 3000);             
}

 window.setTimeout(function() {
            glob.val = true;
        }, 3000);
```

As you can see I try to change `val` to `true` after 3 sec by 2 ways but no one is working for me. Really strange. Did I miss something?

Actually I try to change value after get response from Ajax, but suppose should be the same problem.

Thanks,

Here is my example:  http://jsfiddle.net/6uKAT/20/

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try using: [`$timeout`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout)

> Angular's wrapper for window.setTimeout. The fn function is wrapped
>   into a try/catch block and delegates any exceptions to
>   $exceptionHandler service.

`$timeout(fn[, delay][, invokeApply]);`

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uKAT/22/)

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

function Ctrl($scope, $timeout) {  
     $scope.val = false;
     $timeout(function(){$scope.val = true}, 3000);       
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that, actually I try to change value after get response from Ajax, but suppose should be the same problem.

Comment: In order to answer that specific question I may need to see an real example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @HereHere - Simply saying "Not working" isn't very helpful. Is there a specific error you're seeing? It's possible that the function has changed since this was answered, but the link should still be relevant (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Answer (score 27):

You are making changes to scope outside of what angular knows about (inside a timeout).
So you should use `$timeout`.. otherwise you have to use `$scope.$apply()`

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.val = true;
}, 3000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6uKAT/21/

For timeout use `$timeout` and it will call `$scope.$apply()` for you.
Likewise, for ajax use `$http`.

if you can't use these, then you must call `$scope.$apply()` yourself:

```
 window.setTimeout(function() {
     $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.val = true;
     });
 }, 3000);
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning $apply for ng-newbs like my self, [here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) is a great explanation :