# Why is ng-disabled not making button enabled after 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <script src="js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/using built-in directives.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Using ng-disabled directive</h1>
        Name:<input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
        <br/>
        <button ng-disabled="!name" >sign in</button>

        <hr/>
        <h1>Button enabled after specified number of seconds </h1>
        <button ng-disabled="isDisabled" >sign in</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

**using built-in directives.js**

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.isDisabled = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $rootScope.isDisabled = false;
    },3000);
```

In the beginning when page loads button stays disabled as it should but after 3 seconds it isn't enabled. Why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change value after delay by using angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069309/how-to-change-value-after-delay-by-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `setTimeout`, the model change is done outside angular context, therefore it does not trigger a *digest*.

Replace:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // ...
},3000);
```

with

```
$timeout(function(){
    // ...
}, 3000);
```