# How to apply delay on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using below code, In laravel blade

```
<div ng-show="displayErrorMsg" class="form-group m-b alert alert-danger">{{errorMsg}}
```

In angularjs controller

```
$scope.errorMsg = "Data Empty";
$scope.displayErrorMsg = true;
setTimeout(function() { $scope.displayErrorMsg = false;}, 2000);
```

Message not disappear after 2 second automatically as given.

But when I simply put alert("test"); or click anywhere message disappears.
How to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Long-complex answer, you need to use angular service to let angular know when something changed and update all the `scope`s and view. ---- short-answer, go for answer of @Imtiaz Pabel or @searching... and use `$timeout` :-)

Comment: Thanks all ,it's working.. :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just inject `$timeout` in your controller and use this.

```
$timeout(function() { $scope.displayErrorMsg = false;}, 2000);
```

Also you can use $digest or $apply as below

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.displayErrorMsg = false;
    $scope.$digest();
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function () {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.displayErrorMsg = false;
  });
}, 2000);
```

Check here how these works,

http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Answer (score 8):

I usually need a function to wait a little bit for any reason, **for testing purposes only**. In Java, we can use the Thread.sleep(). However, In JavaScript I prefer to use a simple function I found [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/delay-sleep-pause-wait/):

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

It has been working for me in several scenarios, including AngularJS. But, please, *remember that function shouldn't be used in production environments unless you know exactly what you're doing*.

Answer (score 4):

Example 1: setTimeout

```
var timerCount = function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.displayErrorMsg = false;
        $scope.$apply(timerCount);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Example 2: $timeout

```
$timeout(function() { 
    $scope.displayErrorMsg = false;
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use angular timeout,for more https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

or [How to change value after delay by using angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069309/how-to-change-value-after-delay-by-using-angularjs)

```
$timeout(function() { $scope.displayErrorMsg = false;}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can inject $timeout. Angular's warapper window.setTimeout method.

try this one :-

```
$timeout(function() { $scope.displayErrorMsg = false;}, 2000);
```

the structure of $timeout is
synatx:-
$timeout(fn,delay,invokeAny,pass)

fn- function that you want to delay

delay: - duration time

invokeAny: - it will set false by default otherwise it will call function fn within $apply block

pass : - it is optional parameter to execute the function.

**Another Approach:-**

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.displayErrorMsg = false;
  });
}, 2000);
```

the setTimeout method run out of Angular Context so we need to call $apply that will call $digest cycle because if we update $scope inside setTimeout Angular need to know $scope gets dirty.

Answer (score 2):

## Improved solution 1 :

```
$scope.errorMsg = "Data Empty";
$scope.displayErrorMsg = true;
if (timer) $timeout.cancel(timer); // restart counter
timer = setTimeout(function() { $scope.displayErrorMsg = false;}, 2000);
```

## Solution 1 :

You can use [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) :

```
$scope.errorMsg = "Data Empty";
$scope.displayErrorMsg = true;
setTimeout(function() { $scope.displayErrorMsg = false;}, 2000);
```

## Solution 2 :

With setTimeout :

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.displayErrorMsg = false;
    });
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout is method of window object. So in order to access this function inject **$window** in controller.
Then you can call any method like alert, confirm, setTimeout, setInterval etc. 
Details https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window 
Then You can write

```
$scope.errorMsg = "Data Empty";
$scope.displayErrorMsg = true;
$window.setTimeout(function() { $scope.displayErrorMsg = false;}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Synchronous solution:**

```
const sleep = ( ms ) => {
    const end = +(new Date()) + ms;
    while( +(new Date()) < end ){ } 
}
```

**Example:**

```
(function() {
    console.log(+(new Date())); // 1527837689811
    sleep(1000);

    console.log(+(new Date())); // 1527837690813
    sleep(2000);

    console.log(+(new Date())); // 1527837692814
    sleep(3000);

    console.log(+(new Date())); // 1527837695814
    sleep(4000);

    console.log(+(new Date())); // 1527837699814
    sleep(5000);
})();
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanantion to your code?